# writing C / C++ bindings and libraries for PHP

Tags: php, c++, c, bind

Im looking for examples and further information on writing c / c++ libs / bindings for PHP environment? if anyone could reccomend a good place to start?

Comment: Seriously? You couldn't search for "PHP C++ module"?

Comment: ok i will edit the q, to be more specific. Criticism taken on board

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you can write a PHP extension to do this.

Follow the tutorial here: http://devzone.zend.com/303/extension-writing-part-i-introduction-to-php-and-zend/

There's also a SO topic: [How to make a PHP extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632160/how-to-make-a-php-extension)