# Having issues creating an php extension

Tags: php, c

I try to make a custom php extension for code Encryption purposes,

I followed this tutorial to make an custom extension: [How to make a PHP extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632160/how-to-make-a-php-extension)

i get this warning  when compiling the extension:

```
WARNING
The following arguments is invalid, and therefore ignored:
 --enable-php-helloworld
```

i did all according to the tutorial, i build on windows.

what are possible things i do wrong.

I followed that section: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32575493/3103078

I replicated the code 1:1 (Os: Windows)

used commands:

```
phpize
configure --enable-php-helloworld
nmake
php -d extension=php_helloworld.so --re php_helloworld
```

Expected result:

```
>>>helloworld support
```

Actual Result:

```
>>>
```

reproduction:

```
mkdir php
start https://altushost-swe.dl.sourceforge.net/project/winflexbison/win_flex_bison3-latest.zip
set path=%path%;C:\your_path\to\bison 
start https://altushost-swe.dl.sourceforge.net/project/gnuwin32/sed/4.2.1/sed-4.2.1-bin.zip 
set path=%path%;C:\your_path\to\sed
start https://codeload.github.com/skvadrik/re2c/zip/refs/tags/2.1.1
set path=%path%;C:\your_path\to\re2c
start https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/C/3/5C3770A3-12B4-4DB4-BAE7-99C624EB32AD/windowssdk/winsdksetup.exe
rem after install
set path=%path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x64
start https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-devel-pack-7.3.29-Win32-VC15-x64.zip
rem install upper in php dir
phpize
configure --enable-php-helloworld
nmake
php -d extension=php_helloworld.so --re php_helloworld
```

Comment: There is a lot of different info in that post. What were the exact steps you performed? Please provide the precise and exact info. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You should probably share your code, and what are the steps you took to compile? You say "I followed this tutorial" - but if the tutorial is accurate (it possibly isn't), then you couldn't have followed all the steps, right?

Comment: I added additional info

Comment: You still haven't shared your code. This is *not* a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: I now provided a reproduction guide

Comment: and i literally followed the guide 1:1 (For windows) this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32575493/3103078 SO the code is the same as in the guide

Answer (score 1):

The issue was not utilizing the php-src inside the sdk.

Also, on windows you need to use php-sdk-binary-tools, else it wont work when you compile it.

I'll do a tutorial on this soon.